# Lagging and differencing variables

Tags: python

I am tying to do two things:

1. Lag variables in Python; and
2. Difference them.

I tried using the `tail` method for the lag, but it seems to be an inefficient way to do so. var is a basic time series variable or any nx1 vector.

```
var-var.tail(len(var)-1)
```

Can anyone please give me some guidance?

Comment: what is the type of `var`?

Comment: var is a basic time series variable or any nx1 vector.

Comment: please update your question and provide more context. For example: which library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) Series functionality

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> t = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> t
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int64
>>> t.shift(1)
0   NaN
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
dtype: float64
>>> t-t.shift(1)
0   NaN
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
dtype: float64
```

See more in the description of [time series functionality](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)